# Cors proxy issues within server.js file(react, express,sql)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express, cors

I have made a basic fullstack website using mssql and express. Originally the get routes worked but after implementing the post route they have stopped.

I believe I am receiving a cors error which is.

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /admin-view-users from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const sql = require("mssql");
var cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

const config = {
  user: "sas",
  password: "Mypassword456",
  server: "DEVSQL_2014", // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
  database: "TestDBWebsite"
};

//AdminView users just pulls the users from the database

app.get("/admin-view-users", cors(), function(req, res) {
  // connect to your database
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query("select * from Users2 ", function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      // send records as a response

      res.json(recordset);

      res.end();
    });
  });
});

app.get("/admin-view-users", function(req, res) {
  // connect to your database
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query("select * from Users2 ", function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      // send records as a response

      res.json(recordset);

      res.end();
    });
  });
});

app.get("/user-questions", function(req, res) {
  // connect to your database
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query("select * from Questions ", function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      // send records as a response

      res.json(recordset);
    });
  });
});

//

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post("/admin-Add-Users", jsonParser, function(request, response) {
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  var request = new sql.Request();
  // query to the database and get the records

  console.log(email, password); // your JSON
  // echo the result back
  console.log(request.body);

  request.query(
    "insert into Login (email, password) values ('" +
      email +
      "','" +
      password +
      "')",
    function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
  response.send({ message: "Success" });
});

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

I have included "app.use(cors());" which I assumed woudl resolve this but it has not.

Please advice if you can .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes up to my mind is the double use of CORS.

You are putting it uptop in the middleware stack and then calling it again in here:

```
app.get("/admin-view-users", cors(), function(req, res) {
```

Please try using this only once:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors